# Swift: How to use an Array of a Protocol Type inside a SwiftUI ForEach?

Tags: swift, swiftui, protocols

**Context**

Hey there, I am currently working with `Protocols` in `SwiftUI` and encountered a Problem.
I have an `Array` of a `Protocol Type` and would like to use it to populate a `SwiftUI ForEach View`. However, this throws the following error:

> Type 'any Component' cannot conform to 'Identifiable'

---

**Code**

```swift
protocol Component: ObservableObject {
    var name: String { get }
}

struct ComponentsView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ForEach(components) { component in // Error in this Line
            Text(component.name)
        }
    }

    private var components: [any Component] {
        return []
    }
}
```

---

**Question**

- How can I populate my `SwiftUI ForEach View` with the `Array` of `Components`?

Comment: Why does your protocol need to extend ObservableObject and Identifiable? Maybe you are putting to much requirements on your types.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Thanks for your answer, I added ObservableObject since those Components are CoreData Objects used in another Generic SwiftUI View as ObservedObjects. The Identifiable Protocol is not needed right now, so I deleted it.

Comment: I think you are mixing responsibilities here, if ObservableObject is not needed for this list then why does it need to be part of the protocol? If you want to use the protocol for displaying information in a list then make that its only responsibility.

Answer (score 0):

1. Component should have an id to conform to identifiable protocol.
2. The view should take a generic T which conform to Component like below should fix your errors.

```
protocol Component: ObservableObject, Identifiable {
    var id : String { get set }
    var name: String { get }
}

struct ComponentsView<T:Component>: View {
    var body: some View {
        ForEach(components) { component in
            Text(component.name)
        }
    }

    private var components: [T] {
        return []
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however, this does not solve my problem. The `ComponentsView` displays many different `Components`, not one specific one. Therefore, making it Generic does not work.